# Place marker at latitude and longitude of centre of map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Had an issue where I needed to place a marker at the exact centre of my map screen and looked at a lot of questions and answers that were not exactly what I wanted to do.  The app allows the user to move map about and then once crosshairs that are exactly in the centre of the map are at the desired location, you tap a button and a marker appears at that location.

**map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation** almost met my needs but I did not have the coordinates so could not implement that solution.

So my answer hopefully will help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my soltuion was to use the getCameraPosition method as follows.  And its fired from the button R.id.addMarker in my xml.

```
findViewById(R.id.addMarker).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public  void onClick(View view) {
                    if(myMap != null){
                        double myLat = myMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                        double myLng = myMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
                        LatLng markerPoint = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
                        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPoint)).setTitle("next marker");
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Hope it helps someone in the same predicament.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why `fromScreenLocation` doesn't suit your needs...

If you pass the map's width and the map's height divided by two as it's parameters, this function will return you a `LatLng` object giving you the corresponding location in terms of latitude and longitude. After that, it is easy to place a `Marker`at this position.

Comment: More the point I am a newbie still and could not get it to work.  If it is a better solution happy to change my code as I prefer to use best practice where possible.  But all the examples of fromScreenLocation did not work for some reason.

Comment: This part: myMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(screenPoint); AND Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);
    LatLng latLng = 
mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(x_y_points);

Comment: But what doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Is the `LatLng`returned null?... And what about using `LatLng coord=myMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(x_co,y_co));`?